# Postgres - truncate string

Tags: postgresql, truncate

I have a Postgres 9.3 database and I want tidy up a column called filename in a table. The data currently looks like this:

```
C:/TEST/APP/db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
C:/TEST/APP/db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
C:/USP/APP/liquibase/db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
C:/USP/APP/liquibase/db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
```

I want to remove the file path (which may be a variable length) so that I end up with just the file name e.g.

```
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
```

The only way I could see of doing it way for trimming everything to the left of the last / character. 
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [regexp_replace()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html):

```
select regexp_replace (t, '.*/', '')
from (
    values 
    ('C:/TEST/APP/db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml'),
    ('C:/USP/APP/liquibase/db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml')
    ) sub(t)

      regexp_replace
---------------------------
 db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
 db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it overnight I've come up with a rather simple way of doing it using SUBSTR to extract the substring using POSIX regular expression.

```
update databasechangelog
set filename = substring(filename from 'db.1.0.0-RELEASE.*')

Query returned successfully: 517 rows affected, 104 ms execution time.
```

And I now have a tidy column which meets my needs.

```
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
db.1.0.0-RELEASE.data.xml
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it very generic - if you don't know the filename and only that the delimiter is a / character. The table is called databasechangelog and the column name is called 'filename'.

```
select split_part(filename, '/', length(filename) - length(regexp_replace(filename, '/', '', 'g')) / length('/')+1) from databasechangelog
```

Comment: You have better generic solution with `regexp_replace()` in my answer. Try: `select regexp_replace(filename, '.*/', '') from databasechangelog`.